# How do you change the style of cell in a JQuery.DataTable?

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatable, jquery-selectors

I have a question about setting the style attributes for a data cell in the `jQuery.DataTable`.  I was able to set the width for each column when initializing the `dataTable` using the following code:

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns" : [ 
        { sWidth: '40%' }, 
        { sWidth: '60%' }
    ]
} );
```

Now I want to change the alignment for the second column like so: `style="text-align: right;"`.

I am adding rows dynamically using this code:

```
/* Global var for counter */
var giCount = 2;

function fnClickAddRow() {
    oTable.fnAddData( [
        'col_1', 
        'col_2' ] );

    giCount++;  
}
```

Can you tell me how can I select the second cell of the new row after it's been inserted **OR** how to set the style of the row before/during insertion?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Cool, I am happy to report that I was able to answer my own question!  I just defined a CSS style (alignRight), and added the style to the column like so:

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">
    .alignRight { text-align: right; }
</style>

oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {  
    "aoColumns" : [   
        { sWidth: '40%' },   
        { sWidth: '60%', sClass: "alignRight" }  
    ]   } );
```

Comment: Strangely the above code worked only when I have also added the followings:
{ "className": "dt-center", "aTargets": "_all" }

Comment: This is should not be the answer, the question was about adding inline styles not adding classes

Answer (score 10):

you can also use something like that to another kind of customizations :
inside fnRender you can insert label, span, and set class or style of the element inside this "td"

```
"aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Ativo","sClass": "center","bSearchable": true,
                        "fnRender": function(obj) {
                            var sReturn = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                            return "<a href=\"/"+sReturn.toLowerCase()+"\" class=\"tag\">/"+sReturn.toLowerCase()+"</a>";
                        }                   
                    },
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#tblAssignment tr td:nth-child(1)').addClass('rightaligned');
```

Answer (score 7):

Quick and easy way would be to add an `nth-child` class for the table. So in your case:

```
#example td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
<style>
    #tableExample .classDataTable { font-size: 20px; }
</style>

oTable = $('#tableExample').dataTable( {  
    "aoColumns" : [   
        { sWidth: '40%' },   
        { sClass: "classDataTable" }  
    ]   } );
```