# How do I center align dataTables sEmptyTable text?

Tags: css, datatables

My dataTables empty table text is aligned left by default. How do I center align this text?

```
       "oLanguage": {"sEmptyTable": "There are no related records"}
```

Comment: use the **sClass** to add a class then you can style that.

Comment: An example of Riskbreaker's suggestion.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784164/how-do-you-change-the-style-of-cell-in-a-jquery-datatable

Answer (score 0):

just change `class` dataTables_empty.

```
.dataTables_empty{
   text-align: center;
}
```